# Error 127 when running SASS from PHP

Tags: php, ruby, macos, rvm, sass

I'm trying to use SASS from PHP but I always get a 127 error.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
$command = 'sass pathtomyfile.scss:pathtomyfile.css';

system($command, $return); 

echo $return; // give me: 127
```

If I run the exact same command in the terminal, everything work fine. 
Note that I'm trying to do it on Mac OS X.

**Edit:** I believe this is a permission issue but I have no idea of how to solve this.

**Edit 2:** I'm using rvm

Comment: Do you have enough rights to execute the command under your web user?

Comment: I believe I don't but how can I fix that ?

Comment: You should find out with which user you run your webserver. Then you can change to this user and try to execute the command again.

Comment: My web server run with user www-data and if it don't have the rights to execute the SASS command, I believe I need to change the permission of that command to allow www-data to execute it. I did this when I wanted to use java closure compiler with PHP and a simple "chmod 775" on the application solve the problem. But I don't know anything about ruby, and I have no idea of how to do the same thing for the SASS command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127` error is `command not found` make sure the `PATH` is set correctly to a place where `sass` command was installed or full path to the command, you can find the full path to `sass` by running in your shell `which sass`.

As you use RVM you can make sure proper environment is used with wrappers:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3 --install
$ gem install sass
$ rvm wrapper 1.9.3 php sass
$ which php_sass
/home/user/.rvm/bin/php_sass
```

and use the returned path to run `sass`.